Poor network performance with NIC virtio on Virt-Manager on Arch guest
My host is EndeavourOS.
My guest is CachyOS.
When I configure on the Virt-Manager the device model for the NIC to virtio I am getting speed of 1-3 Mbps. My internet is 1Gbps.
When I select device model to Hypervisor Default I am getting more realistic results, 800-900 Mbps.
Why is this happening?
By the way, I had an old Blackarch VM and happened the same (I deleted it thinking it was a VM problem but this wasn't the problem, maybe a bug?)
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:ba:ea:35"/>
  <source bridge="virbr0"/>
  <target dev="vnet7"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x10" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</interface>

